# How can I take away this error from builder: module: put-selector/node-html; dependency: dojox

Tags: ant, builder, dojo

I know that I can ignore this error:

> error(311) Missing dependency. module: put-selector/node-html; dependency:
>   dojox

But is it possible to take out this error? Because this error is disturbing me.
I have a ANT builder, where I want catch true errors. Then, stops the
builder, after to catch the true errors.

But my ANT builder always stops, because there is this error that can be
ignored.